# nodejs server remote connection

Tags: node.js, express, server

I just want a simple http server to control GET and POST request.
I made one using nodejs and express. It works great at localhost. But it's not possible to connect this server remotely. 
I also set static ip address and port forwarding but it's still not possible.
I tried port number 80 and 9000 both are set port forwarding.
Can any one help me?

```html
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 80;

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
    console.log('app.get');
    res.send('abc');
});
app.post('/test', function(req,res) {
    console.log('app.post');
});
http.createServer(app).listen(port,function () {
    console.log('createServer');
});
```

Comment: When you're logged into the server, can you ping your app from there?

Comment: You need to make sure that you have a public IP address for the server that your code is running on and that the port and IP address you are using is accessible from the public internet.  Since this question appears to be about network configuration (I'm guessing setting up proper port forwarding on your home router), not about actual coding, it is probably off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The IP address what I'm using is public IP address but I found that this IP address is not accessible from public internet. I have no idea about the reason. I agree with that it's not proper topic for stack overflow. It's was problem of network something.